# How to get the position of fragment in Actionbar tabs with viewpager

Tags: android

In my program i have six tabs and on fragment with a list inside it ,and i want to show different data in the list View every time that i click a new tab.
How can i use the position variable to do this?
actually how can i get the correct position to understand which tab's been selected?

I've tried using this code in onCreate:

```
      tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new 
               TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

by using the position in the above code , it shows incorrect data in the list that is for the other tabs.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you can write this methode in ActivityMain:

```
private void changeTbs(int position) {
        if (position == 0){
            //is in first tab
        }

        if (position == 1){
            //is in seconde tab
        }
        if (position == 2){
           //is in third
        }
```

and do this in `oncreate` methode in MainActivity:

```
PagerViewAdapter ViewPager mMainPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mainPager);
mMainPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

mPagerViewAdapter = new PagerViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mMainPager.setAdapter(mPagerViewAdapter);

mMainPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           //
           //this is your main answer
           //

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                changeTbs(position);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i'll try this now.

Comment: okay, tell  me what is the result, we can fix that together because I did that before

Comment: no again its showing data of first tab in second tab too . they are not in the right order.

Comment: i used this link: http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/ .which worked fine for different fragment for each of the tabs but i want to have one fragment.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using six tabs then you have to assign new fragment for each tab, by doing this you don't need to worry about position of tab. you can add different data after clicking each tab by doing this 
    Instead ActioBar Tab use TabLayout

```
 tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Two"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Three"));

then initialize FirstPagerAdapter  
fpadapter = new FirstPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
tabLayout.getTabCount(), 
this.getApplicationContext());vpager.setAdapter(fpadapter);


class FirstPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumofTabss;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Context mmcontext;

public FirstPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabss = NumOfTabs;
}

public FirstPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int NumOfTabs, Context mcontext) 
{
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentManager = fm;
    this.mmcontext = mcontext;
    this.mNumOfTabss = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragmentone tabf = new Fragmentone();

            return tabf;
        case 1:
            Fragmenttwo tab2 = new Fragmenttwo();
            return tab2;

        case 2:
            Fragmentthree tab3 = new Fragmentthree();
            return tab3;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabss;
}
}
```